# router.navigate in ngOnInit() not working on page reload

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular5

I have this piece of code:

```
public ngOnInit() {
if (featureToggle == false) {
  this.router.navigate([ '/login' ]);
 }
}
```

The requirement is that when the feature toggle is false, the component should not be loaded. So when I copy paste the url, the feature toggle comes out to be false and it enters the if block and executes the navigate statement. But the navigation to login does not work. Please could you help me out.

Answer (score 0):

If featureToggle is a variable within the component , you should use this

```
  public ngOnInit() { if (!this.featureToggle) { this.router.navigate([ '/login' ]); } }
```

Comment: I am doing it this way only. For simplicity sake I have mentioned it in the code (featureToggle == false). :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

If your **featureToggle** is a boolean you can just do like this.

```
public ngOnInit() {
if (!featureToggle) {
  this.router.navigate([ '/login' ]);
 }
}
```

Comment: I think the issue is with routing. It is already entering the if block correctly. This does not seem to work. Thank you!